# Updating the size of a static 2D array before anything has been done to the array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a program that's reading from a file and outputting to a file. When it reads the data from the file its stores it into a 2D array, after computer runs the next few codes it outputs to the file.

Now the initial file has a fixed length of 24, which and the array is declared outside the main

```java
static String [][] table = new String [24][7];
```

Since eventually we will output to the file, the length of the file increase from `24` to `25` Since I can't really changing the size of the array while the code is running, I first used

```java
int lines = 0;
while (reader.readLine() != null) lines++;
reader.close();
```

to get the length of the lines then update the size of the array by recreating the array.

```java
table = new String [lines][7];
```

correct me if I'm wrong but by doing this shouldn't update the size of the array as if I just declared it?

Each time I print to the file the length increase and I want to use the information I output to the file to preform a calculation along with the initial data from the file.
`if you want to see what happens after here`
https://codeshare.io/0grq7g

Comment: When you do `table = new String [lines][7];` all the data will be lost that was stored in table.

Comment: i know, but since the data changes meaning ```table``` becomes empty each time the program runs, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When assigning a new String array to the `table` variable, you create a pointer to a *new* array. You could expand the table using a loop and `System.arraycopy(...)`:

```
String[][] resizeArray(String[][] src, int newSizeX, int newSizeY) {
    String[][] result = new String[newSizeX][newSizeY];
    int maxX=newSizeX<src.length?newSizeX:src.length;
    for(int x=0; x<maxX; x++) {
        System.arraycopy(src[x],0,result[x],0,newSizeY<src[x].length?newSizeY:src[x].length);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
table = resizeArray(table,lines,7);
```

---

**Edit:** I think I misunderstood OP's question. The Array increases in size, because you are adding *two* `\n`'s for each player added and therefore the number of lines does not equal the number of players anymore. You could either leave out the first `\n` or you could divide the resulting `lines` variable (after the `reader.close()`) by 2.
For the first method you can change your code to:

```
for (i = 0; i < add; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter in the Folowung order: Player GP  G   A   P   +/- PIM PPG PPP SHG SHP GWG OTG S   S%  FO%");
    //writer.write("\n");
    for (j = 0; j < 15; j++)
    {
        
        String word = scan.next();
        writer.write(word + "\t");
    }
    writer.write("\n");
     
}
```

Comment: I added ```writer.write("\n");``` because it would not write to a new line in the file

Comment: Or if you want a seperating empty newline for each entry, you can divide the lines by two for the reallocation, as I stated. I.e.: `table=new String[lines/2][7];`

Comment: The main issue with the code is that it would not store the new player i add into the array, because the size of the array is set to 24 and there are initially 24 lines in the .txt file it ignores the new line. Which is why i checked how much lines are in the .txt file and tried to change the size before anything is stored in the array. 
**EDIT:** I tried ```table=new String[lines/2][7];``` but it just ignores the new player added also

Comment: @J-Khai You probably want to initialize the `input` Scanner *after* closing the writer via `writer.close();`, but I am not currently at my PC so I cannot verify.

Comment: with the first method i get an array out of bound for the length of 24, and the seconds one prints player to file but still ignores the player

Comment: @J-Khai For the IndexOutOfBoundsException: The other arrays also need to be updated to match the new `table`'s size. (`arrGoals`, `arrAssists`, `arrPoints`).

Comment: I know but the size of those arrays are set as ```table.length```

Comment: @J-Khai But you change `table.length`, so you need to change those arrays aswell to reflect the change

Comment: When i made an static variable called length and store ```table``` length in it, the variable length did not get updated, ```Index 1 out of bounds for length 0``` why?

Comment: @J-Khai the variable doesn't magically update when `table.length` changes. Same goes for the Arrays. After doing `table = new String[...][...]`, you also have to do `arrGoals=new int[table.length];`, `arrAssists=new int[table.length];` and `arrPoints=new int[table.length]`